# $\operatorname{Re}$ and $\operatorname{Im}$ of $\frac{1+it}{1-it}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $w = \frac{1+it}{1-it}, w \in \mathbb C, t \in \mathbb R$

**Question**: How to calculate $\operatorname{Re}(w)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(w)$?

What I have done so far:

$
\begin{align}
w &= \frac{1+it}{1-it} \\
  &= \frac{(1+it)(1+it)}{(1-it)(1+it)} \\
  &= \frac{(1+it)^2}{1+it-it-(it)^2} \\
  &= \frac{(1+it)^2}{1-(it)^2}
\end{align}$

However I am running in a circle here and this does not really help me. Is there a technique to simplify complex numbers containing an additional variable?

Comment: You're actually very close; note that $(it)^2$ is a real number, namely $-t^2$. Now expand the numerator of your fraction and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there:$$\frac{(1+it)^2}{1-(it)^2}=\frac{1-t^2+2it}{1+t^2}=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}+\frac{2t}{1+t^2}i.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the denominator $1-(it)^2 = 1-i^2t^2 = 1-(-1)t^2 = 1+t^2$, which is real for real $t$. Also expand the numerator into $1 + 2it - t^2$ and then get the real and imaginary parts.